# Finding the line, with leading blanks, starting with the great value

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, grep, uniq

I am using bash commands for sorting some results. My `file_of_counts` basically looks like this

```
 23 (some text),(1 2 3 4 1)
 95 (some text),(1 2 3 3 5)
  9 (some text),(1 2 3 5 5)
 10 (some text),(1 2 3 2 5)
 10 (some text),(1 2 3 4 4)
 45 (some text),(1 2 3 4 2)
```

I got to this point by doing

```
cat myfile | grep some_term | uniq -c > file_of_counts
```

So I found the lines with keyword 'some_term' and then found the unique lines, where `uniq -c`  gives also the count of each unique line, which is what essentially has been described in the example above in `file_of_counts`.

As you can see each line has some leading blank spaces. For some reason I cannot make

```
cat file_of_counts | sort
```

work, or rather it wont give me the correct answer. I must be missing something obvious with the leading blanks or something. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `-n` switch :

```
$ sort -rn file
```

#### OUTPUT :

```
 95 (some text),(1 2 3 3 5)
 45 (some text),(1 2 3 4 2)
 23 (some text),(1 2 3 4 1)
 10 (some text),(1 2 3 4 4)
 10 (some text),(1 2 3 2 5)
  9 (some text),(1 2 3 5 5)
```

from `man sort` :

```
    -n, --numeric-sort
           compare according to string numerical value
```